# Statistical significance of change between two periods of time

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance

I have data on a group of individuals who have been given a new tool to trial on to help with reducing the average time needed to perform certain task. There are two metrics we look at to measure performance, overall reduction in average time performing a task, and the percent accuracy of the completed task. The overall goal is to reduce the amount of time needed to complete the task without significantly impacting accuracy rate of the completed tasks.

Prior to the trial period, on average the individuals are given 1,500 tasks to complete per month, with the average time of completion around 35 mins, and accuracy rate of 90%. With the new tool, the average time of completion has improved to average of 30 mins to complete a task. But the accuracy rate has dropped to 88%.

I was asked to give recommendation if we should continue with the tool, however I’m not certain how to determine if the performance difference is statistically significant. What is the appropriate test or calculation I can use to determine this?

Comment: You need to tell us some details about how you measure performance!

Comment: In addition to that, it might be useful/important to know how the cost associated with a decrease in accuracy compares with the cost associated with an increase in completion time. It might be that that the decrease in accuracy is "statistically significant" but that the gains (in terms of efficiency) still exceed the costs (in terms of accuracy). So, it could be more useful to make an actual cost-benefit analysis.

Comment: The performance is measured by looking at the two metrics (average time completing task, overall accuracy rate) during the trial period (1 month), against their average baseline performance before implementing the new tool. And all tasks are randomly assigned to the group of individuals.

Would the paired t test be appropriate to measure the statistical significance of the change in two performance metrics?